# MAX232 vs TRS202EC Line Drivers

Tags: uart, driver, rs232, transceiver, max232

I have used MAX232 as UART serial line driver using 5V power supply. Now I have come across [TRS202](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/trs202.pdf) chip in a circuit. It also run with 5V power supply. Does this chip has some special difference or is it replaceable by MAX232 chip?

[image]

Edit: correction in above info.

Comment: You might want to ask if anyone has had a good or bad experience performing the above substitution or even just adopting the new part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TRS202 uses smaller capacitors. I guess that the switching frequency is higher for the switched capacitors. With the capacitors it doubles the +5V to +10V and then makes it negative to -10V. For the MAX232 you need 1uF capacitors and for the TRS202 you need 0.1uF capacitors (but 1uF is also ok. max 10uF). Both are pin compatible, but keep the value of the capacitors in mind. The TRS202 is based on the MAX202.

Answer (score 1):

The specifications of these two devices are similar but not identical. Whether that matters in your application is something that only you can decide.

Comment: My application is a simple industrial motor driver in which the Main board and the LCD (dot matrix) boards are connected by UART RS232 port. Both boards are sitting next to each other and low baud rate. If i replace the TRS202 with MAX232 along with any changes required then would it be safe to assume that no loss of functionality will occur?

Comment: I wouldn't assume that the TRS202 is a drop-in replacement for the MAX232 unless you check all of the differences between the specifications of these two parts and convince yourself that they don't matter to you.